How to find the linear transformation knowing one input and its output
I'm trying to find the linear function when I know one input vector and its respective output vector.

Let $L: \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R^2$ be a linear operator. If $L((1,2)^T) =(−2,3)^T$.

The $T$ beside the vectors indicates "transpose".
My approach was to use the equality: L(v) = Av where L is the linear transformation and v is the input vector.
However I substitute those for the values given and I got A(1,2)T = (-2,3)T but I dont know how to solve the equation for A.
Is there a better way to do this?

There are many linear operators that satisfy this equation. Given such an operator $L$ and any operator $P$ satisfying $P\pmatrix{1\2} = {\bf 0}$, $L + P$ also satisfies the condition.

Hint Write the matrix representation $A$ as $A = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$. Substituting in $A \pmatrix{1\\2} = \pmatrix{-2\\3}$ gives the $2 \times 4$ linear system
\begin{align}
a + 2 b &= -2 \\
c + 2 d &=  3 ,
\end{align}
which is conveniently now in echelon form. Now any choice of $a, b, c, d$ satisfying the two equations gives an $A$ (hence $L$) that satisfies the condition. Since this linear system is underdetermined (there are more variables than equations), if there is one solution, then there are infinitely many.

Setting $b = c = 0$ gives the solution $\pmatrix{-2&0\\3&0}$. We can write the general solution as $\pmatrix{-2&0\\3&0} + \pmatrix{p\\q} \pmatrix{2&-1}$, $p, q \in \Bbb R$.

